# Создание браузерной видеоигры

Tags: разработка-игр

Доброго времени суток. Недавно я столкнулся с вопросом о создании браузерной видеоигры. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие языки программирования или может быть какие-либо библиотеки для создания браузерных видеоигр.

Comment: Чувствую, что сейчас вам вперемешку начнут советовать `Flash`, `Unity`, `HTML5` и `Chrome NaCl`.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не полон - Crysis, DOOM 2 и марио - разные игры. И для их реализации нужны разные инструменты.

Если логику и коммуникации можно много на чем сделать - то инструменты для работы с графикой более узконаправлены.

Второй момент - под *какие платформы* вы эту игру хотите - на iPAd и Android тоже есть браузеры и под них тоже можно "шпилить" ))